# Why list preserves the value of another null list in c#

Tags: c#

I was going through differences between Stack and Heap and tried something to understand the reference type and value type variables. What I understood is that a reference type holds the address of value stored in heap and if the value in heap is changed all the reference to that address will point to new value, so I played with below codes but I am wondering why the below code prints a value of `10` when `lt1` is set to `null`:

```
public void Method4()
{
    List<int> lt1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    List<int> lt2 = lt1;
    lt1 = null;
    int xx = lt2.Sum();
    Console.WriteLine(xx);
}
```

But it prints `0` when `lt1` is cleared.

```
public void Method4()
{
    List<int> lt1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    List<int> lt2 = lt1;
    lt1.Clear();
    int xx = lt2.Sum();
    Console.WriteLine(xx);
}
```

I think `lt2` holds the reference of `lt1` and when `lt1` is set to null then `lt2` should also be null but this is not the case.

What is going on in the background?

Comment: You're confusing the container with the contents. A variable is a container for a value. You're copying the value from one variable to another.

Comment: "lt2 holds the reference of lt1 and when lt1 is set to null then lt2 should also be null" - no, lt2 holds a reference to the same *object* that lt1 holds a reference to. When lt1 is set to null, it no longer holds a reference to that original object.

Comment: @Jacobr365 - that seems irrelevant since there are no parameters here at all.

Comment: So If I understand this correctly then when I initialize the first list values 1,2,3,4 are stored in heap with some address let's say "xyz" and when I initialize list2 which is equals to list1 then list2 also point to address "xyz". Now when lt1 is set to null, it no longer points to "xyz" but the values 1,2,3,4 are still at the same address. In second case when list1 is cleared then the values at address "xyz" is cleared hence it is returning 0 as a result of sum??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of ideas conflated here.  For a conceptual overview, I would highly recommend Jon Skeet's Variables, References, and Objects explanation [here](https://youtu.be/jGUoF-uByGg?t=677).

We can also examine each example and comment on what is going on:

### Nulling out `lt1`:

We can break down the following method

```
public void PrintsTen()
{
    List<int> lt1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    List<int> lt2 = lt1;
    lt1 = null;
    int xx = lt2.Sum();
    Console.WriteLine(xx);//prints "10"
}
```

line by line.

First:

```
List<int> lt1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

- This is a local declaration statement that declares a variable.

  - Declare a variable `lt1` of reference type `List<int>` inside the `PrintsTen` scope.
  - Create a new object (the object itself lives on the heap) of type `List<int>` which contains the values `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`
  - Set the variable `lt1` to reference/"point to" the object on the heap we just created with the `new` portion of the expression

Second:

```
List<int> lt2 = lt1;
```

- This is a local declaration statement that declares a variable.

  - Declare a variable `lt2` of reference type `List<int>` inside the `PrintsTen` scope.
  - Set the variable `lt2` to reference/"point to" the object on the heap that `lt1` references/"points to".

    - `lt2` references/"points to" the `List<int>` on the heap.
    - **This is the list object we created with the `new` call in the previous line.**

Third:

```
lt1 = null;
```

- This is an simple assignment statement (expression statement which contains a simple assignment expression).

  - Assign the `lt1` variable to reference/"point to" `null` (nothing).

    - This ***does not*** change what `lt2` points to!

Fourth:

```
int xx = lt2.Sum();
```

- This is a local declaration statement that declares a variable.

  - Declare a variable `xx` of value type `int` inside the `PrintsTen` scope.
  - Set the variable `xx`equal to the value returned from the invocation of the `Sum()` method on the object referenced by `lt2`

    - Because `lt2` references/"points to" the list object which contains `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` the result will be the value `10`.

Finally:

```
Console.WriteLine(xx);
```

- This is an invocation statement (expression statement which contains an invocation expression).
- The `WriteLine` method prints the value of `xx` (which is `10`) to the console window

---

### Calling `Clear()` on `lt1`:

We can follow a similar explanation for the following method

```
public void PrintsZero()
{
    List<int> lt1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    List<int> lt2 = lt1;
    lt1.Clear();
    int xx = lt2.Sum();
    Console.WriteLine(xx);//prints "0"
}
```

line by line as well.

First:

```
List<int> lt1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

- This is a local declaration statement that declares a variable.

  - Declare a variable `lt1` of reference type `List<int>` inside the `PrintsZero` scope.
  - Create a new object (the object itself lives on the heap) of type `List<int>` which contains the values `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`
  - Set the variable `lt1` to reference/"point to" the object on the heap we just created with the `new` portion of the expression

Second:

```
List<int> lt2 = lt1;
```

- This is a local declaration statement that declares a variable.

  - Declare a variable `lt2` of reference type `List<int>` inside the `PrintsZero` scope.
  - Set the variable `lt2` to reference/"point to" the object on the heap that `lt1` references/"points to"

    - `lt2` references/"points to" the `List<int>` on the heap.
    - **This is the list object we created with the `new` call in the previous line.**

Third:

```
lt1.Clear();
```

- This is an simple invocation statement (expression statement which contains an invocation expression).

  - Because `lt1` references/"points to" the list object which contains `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`, **`Clear()` will empty the list object on the heap to contain no elements.**

    - Since this changes the list object itself, and `lt2` also points to the that same object, **`lt2` references/"points to" the empty list.**

Fourth:

```
int xx = lt2.Sum();
```

- This is a local declaration statement that declares a variable.
- Declare a variable `xx` of value type `int` inside the `PrintsZero` scope.
- Set the variable `xx`equal to the value returned from the invocation of the `Sum()` method on the object referenced by `lt2`

  - Because `lt2` references/"points to" the list object which contains no elements the result will be the value `0`.

Finally:

```
Console.WriteLine(xx);
```

- This is an invocation statement (expression statement which contains an invocation expression).
- The `WriteLine` method prints the value of `xx` (which is `0`) to the console window

Comment: Only one word for this explanation - WOW!!!.. but I have one more question here, somewhere I read that "New" key word is used to call the constructor of a class , but if we are creating an object of class, constructor will be automatically be called, so I am a bit confused with the lines you have written about "new" key word in your explanation. could you please elaborate more on this thing.

Comment: Did you have a chance to watch the video I linked in the answer?  If not, I **highly** recommend watching as soon as you get a chance [here](https://youtu.be/jGUoF-uByGg?t=677).  :-)  Once you've taken a look at the video, using Jon Skeet's analogies: the `new` keyword is conceptually responsible for actually building the house.  First, an address for that house is chosen and the lot size is defined (this is where the memory is allocated for the object's use), then the house itself is built (this is where the constructor is called).  Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, since you seem to be a new member, I thought these guidelines may be helpful: [http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

- lt1 holds the pointer to a list
- lt2 holds the pointer to a list

If you edit the list **items** "in lt1", they are also edited "in lt2", because they are edited *in the list*, not in the pointer.

But you are telling "lt1 should now point to null". This **does not** mean that lt2 should point to null.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
List<int> lt2 = lt1;
```

You're assigning `lt2` to point to the same location in memory that `lt1` is currently pointing to.  If you then go on to do this:

```
lt1 = null;
```

That only  means that `lt1` no longer points to any location in memory -- more importantly it no longer points to the same location in memory that it previously shared with `lt2`; however `lt2` *still* points to that location, which is why `lt2.Sum()` still works.

Clearing the memory reference that `lt1` points to does not affect `lt2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
lt1 = null; // changing the pointer of lt1 does not also change that pointer of lt2
```

In your 1st example all you are doing is changing the pointer to the `List<int>` for variable `lt1`. `lt2` still points to that `List<int>` so it will return 10 when `Sum` is called. You have not made any actual changes to the underlying object on the heap, only changed the address of `lt1` so it no longer points to that object.

---

```
lt1.Clear(); // its the same list on the heap but now you are calling a method on that list called Clear which removes the items on that list.
```

In your 2nd example you have a single `List<int>` (again) but you call the member on that object to clear its content which will result in an empty list. You have changed the underlying object, not the pointer to that object. This is why the Sum will return 0. An empty list is not the same as a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `lt1` to `null` you are not changing the *value* of that variable but only the *reference*.

With `lt1 = null` you are telling the compiler that `lt1` should no longer point to the `List<int>` you created in the first line of `Method4()` but should instead point to *nothing* (i.e. `null`).

The difference between `lt1 = null` and `lt1.Clear()`is exactly that the first changes the *reference* `lt1` itself whereas the latter changes the *value* that `lt1` is *referencing*.

Answer (score 0):

A variable storing a reference of an instance is like a sheet of paper where you write down the adress of a building.

If I make a copy of the sheet of paper then I have 2 sheets (variables) with the same address (reference) but I will not have 2 buildings (instances).

If I paint the building (instance) at the adress (reference) on the copied sheet of paper (variable) in red (setting a property of the instance) also the building (instance) at adress (reference) of the original (variable) will be red, because it was the same building (instance).